# Selecting elements by class with Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

Hi I am trying to parse data from yahoo finance using Jsoup in Eclipse by selecting elements by their class with the below code.

This method has worked for me with other website but will not work here. The attached link is the [page I'm trying to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmiJu.png). In this example the line I'm trying to parse 21.74 specifically I want to parse out the "21.74". I have tried selecting table elements but nothing seems to work. This is my first question so any suggestions are mush appreciated!!

```
public static final String YAHOOLINK = new String("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MMM/key-statistics?p=");
private String yahooLink;
private Document rawYahooData;
private static String CLASSNAME = new String("W(100%) Pos(r)");
public YahooDataCollector(String aStockTicker){
    yahooLink = new String(YAHOOLINK + aStockTicker);
    try 
    {
        rawYahooData = (Document) Jsoup.connect(yahooLink).timeout(10*1000).get();
        Elements yahooElements = rawYahooData.getElementsByClass(CLASSNAME);
        for(Element e : yahooElements)
        {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Grabbing Raw Data For "+ aStockTicker);
    }       
}
```

Comment: <td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)">21.74</td> - this is the line

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what "nothing seems to work" means.  Preferably with the outputs you're getting.

Comment: @JoeC sorry for being vague, but thats part of the problem, my code is not finding anything on the web page that matches the class "CLASSNAME" so I am not getting any output at all.

Comment: Well, the class you've highlighted in your image doesn't match that class either.  So that might be a good place to start.

Comment: @JoeC  Ahh sorry my mistake; however, replacing the class with the one from the image doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: What is the value of "aStockTicker" ? You should edit your question ... As Joe C said, read the checklist before posting :)